# How to get the event logs of Raspberry Pi GPIO pins?

Tags: logging, raspberry-pi3

I am new to Linux and Raspberry Pi. 
I have a Smart home project building over Raspberry Pi and Raspbian. 
I need to build an activity log to show the activities of all GPIO pin that connected to sensors and LED.

So the question is, where can i get the event log showing the operation of each pins with date and time?

Thank you very much